# Converting Position of SKEmitterNode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to convert the SKEmitterNode position to the view, but I don't know how. I've tried using the code to convert SKSpriteNode from Apple, but it doesn't work. Here is my original code, which doesn't work:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent: UIEvent?) {

let traces: [SKEmitterNode]? = self.trace!.children as? [SKEmitterNode]

if (traces != nil && traces?.isEmpty != nil) {
    for trace in traces! {
        trace.particlePosition = (touches.first?.locationInView(trace))!
    }
```

Comment: Try printing the location  and locationInView method takes view as a parameter. Any errors you get try checking if you even enter the if condition

Comment: I would ask myself why am I doing this?  You shouldn't be mixing UIKit and SpriteKit a lot, so I would rethink how I am writing my code.  Perhaps you should be using `locationInNode(scene)` instead

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it worked, thanks!